# Send formdata through jQueryUI Tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

In the page ?p=u I have the following tabs:

```
<div id='tabs' class='ui-tabs'>
  <ul class='ui-tabs-nav'>
    <li><a href='/?p=clt'>Item<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='/?p=clt&a=mail'>Item<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='/?p=clt&a=admin'>Item<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='/?p=clt&a=add&n=<%=n%>'>Item<span>&nbsp;</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the page ?p=clt&a=add I have a pretty simple scenario:

```
if n = "added" then
  "post to database"
else
  "show formular":
  <form method='post' action='/?p=u&amp;n=added'>
    "inputs and such"
  </form>
end if
```

My problem is, that I dont get ANY of the inputs data through the tab when the form is submitted. What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it might be cause you are trying to use both POST and Get variables in request?

Try to replace variables from the form's action with hidden inputs instead.

```
<form method='post' action='/?p=u&amp;n=added'>
   <input type="hidden" name="p" value="u" />
   <input type="hidden" name="n" value="added" />
   "inputs and such"
</form>
```